# XSL changes are not reflected after Bpel deployment in JDeveloper

Tags: xslt, jdeveloper

I have BPel process and uses an XSL to transform the output.

But the changes in the XSL are not reflected after Deployment in JDev (10.1.3.5)
I have to rename the file to be able to get the new changes and make deploy.

How can I do the get the changes reflected without renaming?

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the *.xsl and compiled the composite application?

Use manual compilation 
or
Tools - Preferences - Deployment - compile before deploying

Comment: Also be sure that you actually edit the xsl that is being send to the server.